# jQuery not working on mobile device

Tags: javascript, jquery, mobile

I was wondering why this code is not working on my mobile device but it works perfectly fine on my desktop. Any help would be greatly appreciated. I tried any browser in my mobile but still it doesn't work

```
var link1= "OLDLINKhere";
var link2 = "OLDLINKhere";



if(jQuery(".flying-widget a").attr("href") == link1 ){

    jQuery(".flying-widget a[href$='"+link1+"']").attr("href","www.fb.com");

}else if(jQuery(".flying-widget a").attr("href") == link2 ){

    jQuery(".flying-widget a[href$='"+link2+"']").attr("href","www.google.com");

}
```

Comment: Will it work when `"www.fb.com"` changes to `"https://www.fb.com"`?

Comment: You should take a look at what href should be: https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_a_href.asp

Answer (score 0):

Please use scheme in your URL, please try `.attr("href","http://www.fb.com");`